# Find point of intersection of two line segments

Tags: geometry

Hello I'm new here so I'm hoping this is the right place for this.

I've been trying to figure out how to get a Point on a line segment, that is the point of intersection with another segment. Here's an example:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK2nM.png)

I have this info:

- the coordinates of A, B, C and D
- Angles OCB, OCD and OCA

I'm trying to get X and Y coordinates of point E. Been trying for quite a while and most articles I've seen only get coordinates when there is a literal intersection between line segments. Or I'm wrong and these can also be applied here. However, I'm unsure. I'm not that great at searching keywords for this particular problem.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have coordinates of $O$?

Comment: According to your picture, E is the point of intersection of CD and AB. If $(X_E, Y_E)$ is needed, just create the equations of AB and CD, and solve them. It is not very clear that which line is expected to parallel to what line?

Comment: @coffeemath sorry, should have mentioned. O is always to the right of C and it does not have a specific coordinate. That's just where the angles start at.

Comment: @Mick Maybe I got the question wrong. By "parallel" I meant point on the line of AB and CD. Perhaps this is a better example [link](http://i.imgur.com/j9IQEYR.png). This here shows how segment CD extends to intersect AB to get E more clearly. Sorry for the confusion, I'm not great at naming specific things correctly.

Comment: In that case, my previous comment remains valid. Since the co-ordinates of A and B are known, we can use two-point form to build the equation of AB. Do the same for the line CD. Solving the two equations will give us $E = (X_E, Y_E)$.

Comment: Ah right, I see. Before this I have also tried https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line but it didn't seem to work except horizontal lines. Thanks, I'll try that.